# How to get the int type matrix from the short matrix matrix product

Tags: eigen

We have two `int8` matrices 
`A = B = [200, 200; 200, 200].` How can we get the int matrix product

`C = A * B` without converting `A` and `B` in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
C = A.cast<int>() * B.cast<int>();
```

If you want to make sure that no temporaries are generated (for casting `A` or `B` to `int`, try

```
C = A.cast<int>().lazyProduct(B.cast<int>());
```

For small (fixed-sized) matrices that is likely equivalent to the standard-product above. What is generated depends on your compiler (and optimization level and target machine).
If the code is performance critical, always benchmark and have a look at the generated assembly.